# Delete files with a particular string in the filename but not other strings

Tags: rm

I have some directories with a very large number of files in them. I am looking to prune these directories by deleting files that have a particular string in them but don't have certain other strings in them.

For example deleting files that have "AAA" in the filename but do not have "BBB", "CCC" or "DDD".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `find` from some top-level directory in which you wich to search for files to delete, recursively:

```bash
find . -type f -name '*AAA*' ! -name '*BBB*' ! -name '*CCC*' ! -name '*DDD*' -print
```

The above would find all regular files in or beneath the current directory.  Out of these files, it will select the files that have names containing `AAA`, deselect files that have names containing `BBB`, `CCC` or `DDD` (each `!` negates the immediately following test), and then print the pathnames of the files that are still selected.

The patterns used here are ordinary filename globbing patterns (not regular expressions).  These need to be quoted to avoid accidentally matching names in the current directory.

To delete the files, change `-print` to `-delete`.

Since `-delete` is a non-standard predicate (albeit a commonly implemented one), using `-exec rm {} +` instead would be the more portable.  This would execute `rm` with as many selected files as possible at a time.

---

In general, with two lists of patterns to include and exclude, assuming `bash` as the shell, and assuming that the filenames should match any of the inclusion patterns, and none of the exclusion patterns:

```bash
include=( '*AAA*' '*123*' )
exclude=( '*BBB*' '*CCC*' '*DDD*' )

or_filter=()
and_filter=()

for pattern in "${include[@]}"; do
    or_filter+=( -o -name "$pattern" )
done
or_filter=( "${or_filter[@]:1}" )  # remove initial -o

for pattern in "${exclude[@]}"; do
    and_filter+=( ! -name "$pattern" )
done

find . -type f \( "${or_filter[@]}" \) "${and_filter[@]}" -print
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. I tried doing some research into how to modify that to also be able to have multiple possible strings in the include section too. I worked out that I somehow need to incorporate a -o option in the first "for pattern" section but keep getting syntax errors when I run it. Is it possible to do that? i.e. have multiple possible include strings where it picks up filenames that have any one of them?

Comment: @TimR75 See updated last bit.

Comment: Many thanks. I was almost there just had the syntax slightly wrong. Much appreciated.